# The fastest way to multiply a matrix with a vector?

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication

Could anyone please suggest any faster way to multiply matrix to vector inside this function?

```
  inline void multiply(
        std::vector< std::vector<double> > &matrix,
        std::vector<double> &vector,
        std::vector<double> &result
    ){
        int size = (int) vector.size();

        result.resize(size);

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
              int j = 0;

            for(; j <= size - 16; j += 16){
                result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j]
                    + matrix[i][j + 1] * vector[j + 1]
                    + matrix[i][j + 2] * vector[j + 2]
                    + matrix[i][j + 3] * vector[j + 3]
                    + matrix[i][j + 4] * vector[j + 4]
                    + matrix[i][j + 5] * vector[j + 5]
                    + matrix[i][j + 6] * vector[j + 6]
                    + matrix[i][j + 7] * vector[j + 7]
                    + matrix[i][j + 8] * vector[j + 8]
                    + matrix[i][j + 9] * vector[j + 9]
                    + matrix[i][j + 10] * vector[j + 10]
                    + matrix[i][j + 11] * vector[j + 11]
                    + matrix[i][j + 12] * vector[j + 12]
                    + matrix[i][j + 13] * vector[j + 13]
                    + matrix[i][j + 14] * vector[j + 14]
                    + matrix[i][j + 15] * vector[j + 15];
            }

            for(; j < size; ++j){
                result[i] += matrix[i][j] * vector[j];
            }
        }
    }
```

This function is called a great number of times during the runtime, so it has a very critical influence for total computation time.

Comment: Even if it's "called [a] great number of times", have you measured and profiled that this really is a bottleneck in your program? Always measure before manual optimization. And always build with optimizations enabled before measuring. And remember that "good enough" often *is* good enough. And when you do manual optimization, remember that it often makes the code quite obfuscated, so good documentation (comments) is a must. Lastly, modern compilers are very good at optimizations, including loop unrolling.

Comment: code appears to be bugged in that `result` is not guaranteed to be set to zero at function start.

Comment: You could use [`Eigen`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: `std::vector< std::vector<double> >` is not (I'm told) particularly efficient. It's better to have a a 1d vector and manipulate the indexes to it.

Comment: You'd better use a ready-made BLAS Level 2 implementation.

Comment: Yes, I've profiled the program and this function makes the biggest time contribution. Depending on initial data, the total execution time may last up to 30 min, but the desired time is 10 min maximum. So, in my case "good enough" is not enough :) btw: I use speed priority in optimization preferences.

Comment: Just curious: did your manual chunking into blocks of size 16 turn out to be faster than a simple `for (j=0; j < size; ++j)`? I would expect a modern compiler to optimize that itself.

Comment: Also another hint: don't use `result[i]` directly to accumulate the sum. Each access to it is a potential cache miss. Instead, use a local variable and at the end of the loop do a single assignment to `result[i] = sum`.

Comment: @sebrockm Making a new result involves memory allocation and could slow this down more depending on the size of result. Morale of the story is, profile.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox of course that needs to be profiled, that's why I declared it a hint and not a fact :) But I'm talking about one single local int. No (heap) allocation will happen. Local variables are usually for free and give much more opportunity for the compiler to apply different optimization techniques. It's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on you hardware, using GPU parallelization (ex: CUDA) might help substantially.